# how to use gnu make tool to update archives?

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

according to the manual you can use such syntax: **libfoo(obj1.o)** , which stands for insert obj1.o to libfoo, i wrote a rule like this:

```
libfoo(obj1.o obj2.o):obj1 obj2
```

this rule only insert obj1.o to libfoo, why it just can not insert obj2.o into libfoo?
what does libfoo(obj1.o obj2.o) really stands for?

Comment: What did you actually write in your makefile? What did actually happen when you ran `make`? How are your *.o files built?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the GNUMake manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Archive-Members):

> To specify several members in the same archive, you can write all the
>   member names together between the parentheses. For example:
>
> ```
>  foolib(hack.o kludge.o)
> ```
>
> is equivalent to:
>
> ```
>  foolib(hack.o) foolib(kludge.o)
> ```

When you `make`, I'm guessing you don't specify the target, so Make chooses the first target, which in your makefile is `libfoo(obj1.o)`.